# Issues compiling C++ Script with OpenCV and OpenCV-Contrib on MinGW g++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, g++, mingw

As a start to a new project, I am wanting to use detect scale invariant images in opencv. To start off, i tried simply compiling and running the example script found from [opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d66/tutorial_feature_detection.html) (though very slightly modified)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

#include <chrono>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;
using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{   
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    CommandLineParser parser( argc, argv, "{@input | box.png | input image}" );
    Mat src = imread( samples::findFile( parser.get<String>( "@input" ) ), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if ( src.empty() )
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image!\n" << endl;
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Input image>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 400;
    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect( src, keypoints );

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

  cout << "Elapsed time in milliseconds: "
        << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
        << " ms" << endl;


    //-- Draw keypoints
    Mat img_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints( src, keypoints, img_keypoints );
    //-- Show detected (drawn) keypoints
    imshow("SURF Keypoints", img_keypoints );
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiled and ran perfectly on mac, having installed opencv via homebrew, and using -std=c++11.

On Windows however (the operating system I need it to work on), I have had multiple different errors which I have investigated and tried to resolve which I will list below, none of which I can get working. I don't exactly mind the method this problem is resolved, Its moreso i cannot get any to work, and overall cant get the script to run.

**Creating OpenCV4.5.5 with Cmake**

I installed OpenCV4.5.5, (tried both with "OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE" enabled and disabled), added OpenCV_contrib-4.x modules folder to OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH, generated for mingw, ran mingw32-make install, and compiled with the include, bin, and lib linked. It compiled fine, though running it resulted in

```
OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: The function/feature is not implemented (This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and 
rebuild the library) in create, file C:\Users\playtech\Downloads\opencv_contrib-4.x\opencv_contrib-4.x\modules\xfeatures2d\src\surf.cpp, line 1029
```

**Creating OpenCV3.4.2 with Cmake**

Saw online that earlier versions of OpenCV might allow me to use SURF, though after doing the same as above but with OpenCV/openCV contrib 3.4.2 and running mingw32-make install, got to 28%

```
[ 28%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_msmf.cpp.obj
```

before being hit with so many errors that they don't fit.

**Using other OpenCV**

I assume that OpenCV needs to be built for MinGW opposed to Vsc or Mac, to be able to compile for MinGW g++, needless to say when trying with the same folder and same g++ command that worked on my Mac, I got

```
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::CommandLineParser(int, char const* const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `cv::samples::findFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::empty() const'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3be): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x42e): undefined reference to `cv::drawKeypoints(cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, cv::DrawMatchesFlags)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4a4): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4db): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4ec): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x510): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x51f): undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x627): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x655): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()'
C:\Users\playtech\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaW9CKk.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK2cv17CommandLineParser3getINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEET_RKS7_b[_ZNK2cv17CommandLineParser3getINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEET_RKS7_b]+0x4b): undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::getByName(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, cv::Param, void*) const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

.
All I really want, is to be able to compile on MinGW g++ windows, and have it run and display the same window as does mac. However this may need to be done doesn't really matter so long as it works.

Also the next step in the project would be to detect images (scale invariant) and their coordinates opposed to just features. If there is an alternative altogether that yields this result better than xfeature SURF recognition, I would also like to know/potentially change to it. Thanks!

Comment: did you enabled it like this? OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON and OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=(Path_to_opencv-contrib)/opencv_contrib/modules

Comment: @InUser I enabled OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE and used the path to the opencv contrib modules in the CMake GUI

Comment: what version is the contrib?

Comment: @InUser Its the source code from the master branch https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master "opencv_contrib-4.x"

Comment: there is no "cv2" here. this is C++. "cv2" is a historical accident of naming, still present in the python bindings.

Comment: undefined references to basic opencv stuff indicate that you haven't linked the required library/module of opencv.